# Rasterize Point layer Error: Wrong value for -outsize parameter

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I am trying to create a Euclidean distance raster from a point layer (in QGIS 3.0.3).  From reading up on this topic in this forum I found that I should rasterize the point layer first.  I also followed the suggestion in that post that I create a field in the point layer and fill it with '1'.

The parameters and the output are shown below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to specify a pixel size (width/height), it's not clear from the dialog whether it wants *cell size* (individual pixel size) or *rows and columns* (how many pixels wide/high to cover the extent), the CMD syntax -ts 0.0 0.0 alludes to rows and columns but if the syntax changes to -tr X Y when you populate these fields it is cell size. Also you shouldn't need to fill a field with 1, putting 1 in the *burn value* should suffice. Note that from the help http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html -tr and -ts are mutually exclusive - you may only specify *one* of these parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, unfortunately adding the resolution cell size (both for -tr and -ts separately and simultaneously) and/or changing the fixed value to burn to 1 (with and without a field to use as burn-in vaule selected) did not change the error in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Michael Stimson commented, the problem is how you're specifying the parameters for resolution. When the field "Pixel" is selected it is implying "Number of horizontal / vertical pixels" i.e. an integer and positive number.
When "Georeferenced Units" is selected it is implying the units in your map (degrees, meters, etc).

Comment: I really appreciate both of your assistance with this matter (and your patience with me as a slow learner).  This fixed the issue.  Thank you so much!