# How to rasterize a river vector file and merge it to another raster layer?

Tags: qgis

I got a river vector file.
I want to rasterize it so that the river is 2 pixels wide.
How do I achieve that in QGIS 3.2.3?

When I try to use vector to raster, I get this and no file is created:

```
Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BURN' : 0, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTENT' : '413885.10813709395,678750.4296324956,6754403.012272906,6909638.055526119 [EPSG:32635]', 'FIELD' : None, 'HEIGHT' : 0, 'INIT' : 0, 'INPUT' : 'C:\\Users\\vvaris\\Desktop\\Uoma\\Uoma10.shp', 'INVERT' : False, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/vvaris/Desktop/asd.tif', 'UNITS' : 0, 'WIDTH' : 0 }
```

GDAL command:

```
gdal_rasterize -l Uoma10 -burn 0.0 -ts 0.0 0.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te 413885.10813709395 6754403.012272906 678750.4296324956 6909638.055526119 -ot Float32 -of GTiff C:\Users\vvaris\Desktop\Uoma\Uoma10.shp C:/Users/vvaris/Desktop/asd.tif
```

GDAL command output:

```
ERROR 1: Wrong value for -outsize parameter.
```

Usage:

```
gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at]

{[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add]

[-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement]

[-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def]

[-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]*

[-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]

[-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/

CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-q]

<src_datasource> <dst_filename>

Execution completed in 0.13 seconds
```

Results:

```
{'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/vvaris/Desktop/asd.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' finished
```

Comment: You need to select a different outsize parameter, units and width are set up as 0

Comment: It didn't help. All I get is empty folder.

Comment: Initially you got the error **ERROR 1: Wrong value for -outsize parameter.**
Do you get the same error again? If that's the case have a look [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285309/rasterize-point-layer-error-wrong-value-for-outsize-parameter) as it might be describing the same error you are getting.

Comment: I don't get it, I either got nothing or black square.
"OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/vvaris/Desktop/asd.tif', 'UNITS' : 0, 'WIDTH' : 2 "
UNITS is still zero for some reason...

Comment: Maybe your shapefile is not projected?

Comment: { 'BURN' : 0, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTENT' : '499980.0,609780.0,6690240.0,6800040.0 [EPSG:32635]', 'FIELD' : None, 'HEIGHT' : 10, 'INIT' : 0, 'INPUT' : 'C:\\Users\\vvaris\\Desktop\\Uoma\\Uoma10.shp', 'INVERT' : False, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/vvaris/Desktop/EEE.tif', 'UNITS' : 1, 'WIDTH' : 10 }

Comment: It created a "rasterised" layer, under it there reads Min: 1.79769e+308 Max -1.79769e+308.

How do I check if my shapefile is projected?

Comment: It is, I just saw the EPSG 32635 code defining WGS 84 / UTM zone 35N. So that is not the issue. Probably the definition of cell size was wrong when you got the black square. Now it is a question of fiddling with all the options, as there arent that many. Check the errors well. I cant do the job for you but I am sure you are very close.

Comment: Is there any other way? This seems unnecessarily complicated task compared to rasterising a curve in gimp.

Comment: Yes, there are many software packages capable of such operation, SAGA GIS, FME, Globalmapper, ArcGIS, GVSIG, etc etc.. But the operation will remain the same, you need to provide them the essential parameters. Here some tutorials on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVaUzsbjPNs).
 By the way, with the answer on 1.79769e+308 Max -1.79769e+308 you might have the answer already. Just check the symbology options. Did you embed height in the cell value?

Comment: Did you read the docs https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html? Width is the width of the output image not line width. You can't control line width with gdal_rasterize. I would rather use WMS server for advanced styles.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the width of the river. 
Once you know that, just use `Convert vector to raster` and select a cell size half the width of the river.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your vector is a line, you cannot ask for a width of 2 pixels. I suggest you to make a buffer around the line to give it the necessary width, then only rasterize your output. Don't forget to specify the output raster resolution (e.g. -tr 10 10 for 10 m pixel) and don't use the -ts option.

note that converting to float is probably not necessary, but you don't mention the type of values in the field used for the conversion.